# Ffmpeg with HLS stream bug (maybe)

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I'm trying to capture a stream and save it as a VOD content using FFmpeg but noticed some wrong behaviours with the application if the stream fails for some time and then restarts (the stream server has a buffer so FFmpeg doesn't catch the error instantly). The log FFmpeg says that it's opening the file for reading and keeps showing this message forever (or at least until I've killed the process manually). Have you ever faced a similar issue? (I'm using the -xerror flag in the command so it should be killed if the stream gives an error).

[console print -> bug of always reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22F29.png)

Comment: Need to see your command and the log.

Comment: @llogan `ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel repeat+level -y -xerror -i <in_path>/playlist.m3u8 -vcodec copy -c copy -f hls -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "<out_path>/chunck_list_JMV%d.ts" -hls_flags append_list <out_path>/playlist.m3u8`. Sorry but I don't have the log now, but when I reproduce the bug I'll update this comment. I have updated the text with a image of my terminal showing the bug.

Comment: Please omit `-hide_banner` option when you provide the log. It hides important information.

Comment: Alright, I'll do this

Comment: @llogan do you know if there is a way to set the time between requests made by FFmpeg when trying to capture a stream by a URL?

Comment: To avoid "HTTP error 429 Too Many Requests"? I don't think there is this option. See recent question [Interval option when downloading HLS format videos published on Internet sites using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66839174/) for some crappy suggestions.

Comment: I'm facing a little different problem. I want to make the requests faster (now it makes a request each ~8 s, I want to configure it to make in maybe ~4 s, because this way the process can catch server errors faster and kill itself to avoid this mysterious bug I'm trying to reproduce). Thank you very much with this help, I'll take a look at the link you shared.

Comment: I don't use much networking stuff. I can only recommend reading the documentation for whatever [protocols](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) and [demuxers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) you are using.

Comment: Alright, thanks again. I'll take a look in those links you shared.